# Not getting auto-suggestion to import cucumber package

Tags: cucumber

I am done with adding dependencies in pom.xml and creating features file with scenario. no issues till this point.
When writing code for step definition, I am not auto-suggestion to import package for Given method. It showing me two options only -

1. Create annotation 'Given'
2. Fix project setup it was displaying option to import package.
   What I am missing here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Updated POM with below dependencies and imported accordingly and it worked. Thanks

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>5.1.3</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```